# SQL Query into Json Data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017, json-query

I have a table which have many column. One column has json value like

```
{
  "RequiredForCompany":1, 
  "RequiredOnScreen":0,
  "Editable":[],
  "Visible":[], 
  "Expression":{},
  "GroupFields":[142,156]
}
```

I want to query into this json value with selecting others column. My query like as

```
SELECT 
    [Name],
    JSON_VALUE(FieldAttributes, '$.GroupFields') AS GroupFields
FROM 
    [std].[Field]
```

But it returns null for groupfields. Any way to query into this value?

Comment: Here is good reference: http://www.allaboutmssql.com/2015/12/sql-server-json-examples-jsonquery.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got a solution by the help of @Zaynul Abadin Tuhin. My query is

```
SELECT [Name], STUFF((SELECT ','+[Value] FROM 
  OPENJSON (FieldAttributes,'$.GroupFields') FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS GroupFields
FROM [std].[Field]
```

It's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

your GroupFields (array)is sequence values container that's why you  have to select like below

```
DECLARE @jsonInfo1 NVARCHAR(MAX) =N'{
"RequiredForCompany":1,
"RequiredOnScreen":0,
"Editable":[], 
"Visible":[],
"Expression":{},
"GroupFields":[142,156]

}';


select JSON_VALUE(@jsonInfo1, '$.GroupFields[0]') as g;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7eba8bf042a27253440ce4b41f440979

So in your case

```
SELECT [Name],
  JSON_VALUE(FieldAttributes,'$.GroupFields[0]') AS GroupFields
FROM [std].[Field]
```

Comment: @Md.AbdulAlim https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7eba8bf042a27253440ce4b41f440979 could you please check this link

Comment: I want get all data into GroupFields not only first value. How can?

Comment: @Md.AbdulAlim https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=10d8365a85bc21fcbcef4c1068b104d8 check the 2nd query in this link

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got a solution by using your process

Comment: Your answer is helpful but not complete. I voted your answer.